# Plist as XML in Atom

Tags: macos, atom-editor

I want to open .plist files as .xml files in Atom. Whenever I open a plist it opens as "Property List (Old-Style)" which is bizarre.

I have this in my `config.cson` but to no avail:

```
"*":
  "file-types":
    h: "source.objc"
    "plist": "source.xml"
```

I really haven't the slightest idea why this is wrong, but it doesn't work.
(<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> -> <kbd>X</kbd> -> <kbd>Enter</kbd> isn't bad, but...)

Answer (score 0):

### Grammar Name is Misspecified

You need to change to use the name of the grammar, not the scope (no quotes necessary for the `plist` either):

```
"*":
  "file-types":
    h: "source.objc"
    plist: "text.xml"
```

---

### Grammars in Atom

On [this page](https://atom.io/packages/file-types) it says how to get the grammars list:

> To see all available grammars registered in your Atom instance, open the Developer Tools Console and execute the following:
>
> `console.log(Object.keys(atom.grammars.grammarsByScopeName).sort().join("\n"))`

So... How do you open the Developer Tools? On Mac it's Cmd+Opt+I and then it's the right most tab ([as mentioned here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-view-console-window-debugger/10098)).

Then you'll see the grammars including the one you need, including:

```
text.todo
text.xml
text.xml.plist
```

And that's it!